# How can hashmap guarantee same `index` for key used again?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

The way a hashmap computes the index is the following code -

```
static int indexFor(int h, int length) {
    return h & (length-1);
}
```

Now assuming a key is used for a second time (lets say another put) and at that time the length has changed. In such a case how does `indexFor` return same index when length was 16 vs when length was 64 ?

Comment: Thanks, but many a times such duplicate cannot be googled up.

Comment: @Jay to me it looks like a different question about the same code - although YMMV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `length` of the hash table changes the whole table has to be rebuilt to make sure every entry is at the place where it should now be. (This is called *rehashing*.)

This is quite an expensive operation, so the code attempts to minimise how often it happens. That's why it's useful to tell the `HashMap` how many elements to expect when first constructing it - it allows it to avoid doing any rehashing while filling the table.

Answer (score 0):

The length is not necessarily the number of items in the hash, but the maximum capacity of the hash.

Usually it's a prime number which is increased whenever there's no space to add additional item. In that case the capacity is increased to the next step and `rehashing` is performed.